# JRuby on Rails vs. Ruby on Rails, what's difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm looking to try out JRuby and JRuby on Rails. I'm having trouble finding information on what's difference between JRuby on Rails and Ruby on Rails.

What's the differences I need to look out for?

---

N.B. This questions is an exact duplicate of [JRuby on Rails vs. Ruby on Rails, what's difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151595/jruby-on-rails-vs-ruby-on-rails-whats-difference), except the original question was answered 2.5 years ago.  I'm hoping for an up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original answer still stands and isn't really time specific. JRuby is just a version of Ruby that runs on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). If you're starting from scratch, just go for plain Ruby. JRuby is mostly useful to people who have existing Java code and would like their JRuby and Java apps to communicate.

Comment: One more great reason to be using JRuby is because it works on google app engine == free hosting

Comment: @stephenmurdoch interesting, do you need to use a particular persistance framework on GAE?

Comment: interesting that it hasn't changed; are standard gems still incompatible?

Comment: @alison, datamapper is the ORM of choice for jRuby apps on GAE because it deals well with BigTable - there's a very recent [jRuby and GAE tutorial](http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/google-app-engine-jruby-sinatra-and-some-fun/) that I was reading earlier today which doesn't use any kind of DB or ORM - hopefully it will help you get started out. good luck